# Is there a duration or rest error in the last bar here?

Tags: notation, beginner

In this example - my understanding is that every bar has four quarter notes, in the third bar, we can see only two eighth notes connected to a half note - does that not make a total of 3 quarter notes? The left hand part has a whole note - so that is okay - correctly equal to four quarter notes for that bar. But in the treble clef part for that last bar, shouldn't there be a quarter rest? (or is that supposed to be optional if the rest is in the end?)

This notation is from a published source - https://krishnadasmusic.com/products/krishna-das-selected-sheet-music-vol-1-digital

[image: example]

This is the full piece -
[image: Score for "Radhe Shyam" by Krishna Das and John McDowell]

Comment: More dots are missing, in the last bars of the fourth and fifth systems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the last bar shown contains only three beats in the treble clef, and no, this is not okay, especially since the bass clef contains four beats.

Since there's a repeat sign, sometimes you might see a situation like this that *would* be okay: if the repeated section started with a pickup (anacrusis); for instance, if there had been one beat before the first full measure, then the last measure would contain three beats and a repeat sign, and the repeated pickup would be the "fourth beat." But that's not the case here.

We can only guess what the correct notation *should* be; perhaps there should be a rest, or perhaps the last note should be dotted. My guess is the latter, since that's an easier mistake to make. But the difference between sustaining the pitch and ending it "early" is minimal.

Comment: Put  a rest in: the poor singer needs to take a breath in somewhere!

Comment: @Tim (That's a good next-level point: notate it as a dotted half and a singer will probably take roughly the final beat as a breath anyway. I make this point often when talking about articulation, staccato, etc: The note duration doesn't really tell you "how long the note lasts." Not really, not most of the time. Instead, they tell you "how long *until the next note starts*." Sometimes choral directors will make a point about sustain, or infinite-sustain instruments like organ can care about cutoff. More often, though, we taper, we breathe, we articulate, and rhythm is composed of attacks.

Comment: I would instead say that the note duration literally does indicate how long the note lasts, but individual singers/players/directors can choose to override the score's information for practical purposes like breathing. As an experienced choral singer, I promise that I want all choral singers to default to "sing the note for the exact duration indicated unless explicitly told otherwise"  :)

Comment: @GregMartin I prefer to sing in groups where the singers are experienced enough to know where to breathe, so the conductor can concentrate on more interesting things such as phrasing, expression, articulation, and form.

Comment: That's a false frame. Experienced singers know there are lots of possible ways and places to breathe, and thus they also know that they need to follow the specific choices of the conductor so that the ensemble sings as one.

Comment: @GregMartin in my experience the quality of a performance tends to be inversely proportional to the amount of time a conductor devotes to communicating note durations to the singers.

Comment: @phoog - so how would your conductor conduct those bars - as writ, or make them full 4/4? Your last comment may ring true for singers, but certainly not for ensemble sections in big bands. They need to be smart in execution, otherwise it all sounds sloppy and amateur.

Comment: @Tim I'm talking generally.  Of course it's necessary to make corrections when the score has errors -- though this should happen before the first rehearsal, not in rehearsal.  And of course the degree to which breaths and note durations must be specified depends on the skill and experience of the performers, the amount of rehearsal time available, and the familiarity of the ensemble with each other and with the conductor.  Groups I've been in that focus on precise duration of notes tend to sound clean and amateur.  I'm not saying _never,_ just that many give it too much weight.

Comment: @phoog - can't imagine barber shop quartets sounding anything but clean and *professional*, with regard to correct breathing! And scores having errors - that may well not be apparent for all parts till a couple of rehearsals have gone by - even for seasoned players. As I found at the last big band rehearsal. Rhythm section reverted to 'playing by ear', which actually worked quite well!

Comment: @Tim there is no lack of very precise, very amateur sounding barbershop quartets on YouTube.  There's more to sounding professional than precise timing of lyrics and breaths -- much more.  And for other kinds of ensembles, especially larger ones in larger rooms, small differences in the lengths of breaths are not going to make a perceptible difference in most cases.  I'd rather focus on giving a compelling dynamic shape to, for example, the imitative counterpoint opening Mozart's Requiem, and on precision of tuning, than on specifying precisely how long each breath must last.

Comment: @GregMartin et alia: 1) I probably shouldn't have gotten us off on a topic that doesn't really bear on the OP's needs, but 2) it's important to note that our understanding of "duration" and "sustain" is parsed along lines of genre. Specifically, the notion that a note is "good to the last drop" until specified otherwise is relatively modern. It goes hand in hand with default notions of sustain (a whole note, marked *f*, means crank out exactly four full beats of homogenous volume). In contrast, early music approaches would assume that a note "lives"—blooms, breathes—in ways that are...

Comment: ... informed by context (swell toward dissonance, relax on resolution, etc etc metric phrasing, text, etc etc). Don't get me wrong; of course you have to worry about ensemble togetherness in Palestrina, and Lully was quite a hardass about it. But that ensemble will often figure out articulations, phrasings, and shapings that may or may not give a whole note exactly 3.9999 beats of sound, often by following performance conventions that are not notated or even discussed, but understood within the micro-music-culture.

Comment: And my take on @phoog's point is that it's not so much that the pros don't care about togetherness—it's that, the more fluent they are in their convention and with each other, *the less they have to talk about it*. You hear less "but *how* swung are these 8ths? are they more or less than two triplets," and a lot more "You'll know it when you hear it"—and they do. From Duke Ellington to Jordi Savall. (But I guess if you *don't* yet, you just have to put in the time, and talk about it, until you do....)

Answer (score 3):

The third bar is wrong.  The upper stave contains three beats, the lower stave contains four.   There's no room here for wriggling, it's just plain wrong.

Probably just a misprint though.   Adding a dot to the final half note would make everything add up.

LATER
Now you've shared the whole piece, we can confirm it's a simple misprint.   There's either a dot or a quarter rest missing from all the short measures.

Answer (score 1):

The recording on which the score is based (linked below) makes clear that each bar should have four beats. The bars in question should have been written either with an extra quarter note (first example below) or with a quarter rest at the end of the bar (second example below). Either one would reflect the musical result demonstrated in the recording: the first would demonstrate the melodic intent but without a breath; the second would demonstrate the breathing, but without the melodic intent.

[image: Example rhythm with ties]

[image: Example rhythm with rest]